# Find between two string date ranges in spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I have Document `Person` like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5e44659dcd"
  },
  "record": {
    "Date_Of_Birth": "9/25/2018"
  },
  "_class": "com.example.entities.Birth"
}
```

`Record` is of type `object`, `Date_Of_Birth` is of type `String` but `Date` has been stored in it and I want to execute query to use $gte and $lte operations on that. I am using spring data mongodb. It seems first I have to use $dateFromString to convert it to date, But this seems to be aggregation which I don't think I require.

Below is the code which I have created so far

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
Query query = new Query(
        Criteria
                .where("record.Date_Of_Birth").gte(DateOperators.dateFromString(startDate).withFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"))
                .andOperator(Criteria.where("record.Date_Of_Birth").lte(DateOperators.dateFromString(endDate).withFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"))
)).with(pageable);
```

which generates this query

```
{ "record.Date_Of_Birth" : { "$gte" : { "value" : { "dateString" : "9/25/2018", "format" : "mm/dd/yyyy"}}}, "$and" : [{ "record.Date_Of_Birth" : { "$lte" : { "value" : { "dateString" : "9/25/2018", "format" : "mm/dd/yyyy"}}}}]}
```

and is not working at all. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you store Date values as strings?

Comment: well... I don't have choice at the moment. The json shared is just a sample. Actual json is quite different and has many other properties. My application would be receiving data and storing as it is in db. So i have to query on what I have for the moment.

Comment: What is the type and format of `startDate`?

Comment: @prasad_ it is of type string and I am passing value of "9/25/2018"

Comment: You are comparing a string to a date.  I suspect you will need to convert the field in the document to date as well, possibly using $expr.

Comment: @Joe could you share complete code example?

Comment: I don't do spring, but I could give an example that would run in the shell

Comment: ok that would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#expr) permits using aggregation operators inside the query.  This will permit you to convert the stored value to a date so you can do an apples to apples comparison.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      {$dateFromString: {
           dateString: "$record.Date_Of_Birth", 
           format: "%m/%d/%Y", 
           timeZone: "EST5EDT"}},
      {$dateFromString: {
           dateString: "9/25/2018", 
           format: "%m/%d/%Y", 
           timeZone: "EST5EDT"}}
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: it's only matching the date "9/25/2018" and not the dates which are greater than that... like "9/26/2018" , etc. what could be the issue?

Comment: I put the $dateFromString clauses in the wrong order. Fixed now

Comment: Thanks! I have modified it to include $lte as well with $and.

Answer (score 0):

Since the date format for the document field `Date_Of_Birth` and the input from-to dates are in string data *and* are formatted as "MM/dd/yyyy" the comparison will not be correct if used as they are.  There are different ways to handle this issue.

Convert both the date formats to "yyyy/MM/dd" strings and compare *or* convert both dates to `Date` objects and compare. Note the sample code shows usage of date values converted to `Date` objects.

To convert the dates for the `find` query, the filter will use the Aggregation date or string conversion operators. The `find` query filter can use Aggregation operators only with the `$expr`operator.

I could not figure clearly to use `$expr` with MongoDB Spring-Data APIs (I suspect there is no such API for handling the `$expr`, but there may be a workaround for that).

The way to run the query clearly is to use an Aggregation. The following are the Mongo Shell and the Spring Data versions.

```
db.persons.aggregate( [ 
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          matches: { 
              $and: [ 
                  { $gte: [ 
                      { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$record.Date_Of_Birth", format: "%m/%d/%Y" } },  
                       ISODate("2018-09-24T00:00:00.00Z") // input from date
                   ] },
                 { $lte: [ 
                     { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$record.Date_Of_Birth", format: "%m/%d/%Y" } }, 
                      ISODate("2018-11-10T00:00:00.00Z") // input to date
                 ] }
              ]
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $match: { matches: true } 
  }
] )
```

The Spring-Data Java code:

```
// Convert the String input dates to Date objects to be used in the query
String from = "9/24/2018";
String to = "11/10/2018";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date fromDt = dateFormat.parse(from);
Date toDt = dateFormat.parse(to);

// Build and run the query
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("record.Date_Of_Birth")
        .and(Gte.valueOf(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("record.Date_Of_Birth").withFormat("%m/%d/%Y")) 
            .greaterThanEqualToValue(fromDt))
                .as("matches1")
        .and(Lte.valueOf(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("record.Date_Of_Birth").withFormat("%m/%d/%Y")) 
            .lessThanEqualToValue(toDt))
              .as("matches2"),
    match(where("matches1").is(true)),
    match(where("matches2").is(true))
);

AggregationResults<Person> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "persons", Person.class);
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```